# Multiprocessing freezing because of semaphore_tracker process in the background

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am using Python Multiprocessing for a project and sometimes the process freezes and apparently the reason why it is happening is this process I find running `ps aux`:

```
python -c from multiprocessing.semaphore_tracker import main;main(39)
```

Some more info:

- If I kill the process everything runs fine
- This problem is not frequent, meaning there could be days running everything fine without it happenning
- I am using PyCharm
- I am runing this Python code in a server using PyCharm remote interpreter and sometime using SSH

**Questions:**

- What is happening that this process is appearing?
- Why isn't it finishing by itself?
- What does it do that freezes other processes?
- How to avoid this situation?

Comment: `semaphore_tracker` as the name implies, is used to track semaphores. Unix supports a limited number of named semaphores, and they're not always cleaned up on process exit. I don't think it's the cause of your program freezing, there's probably some semaphore logic in your program causing that. Try revising your question with your multiprocessing code. More info on semaphore_tracker: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/multiprocessing/semaphore_tracker.py

Comment: I use multiprocessing in a very simple way (just create a list of arguments then call `pool.starmap(func, arguments)`), I don't use anything related to semaphores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods):

> On Unix using the spawn or forkserver start methods will also start a semaphore tracker process which tracks the unlinked named semaphores created by processes of the program.

Why one would *want* to use the spawn start method escapes me. It is a (very clever) bodge necessary on ms-windows because that OS doesn't have the `fork` system call.

So I *suspect* that Pycharm imposes the use of the `forkserver` start method because it uses multiple threads internally, and the standard UNIX `fork` startmethod doesn't deal well with multithreaded programs.

Try running your project from a shell. On UNIX-like operating systems that should default to the `fork` start method that does not require the semaphore tracker process.

Comment: I can't always run the program on a shell because I use a debugger constantly. Any other idea?

Comment: Use `set_start_method` to *force* the use of the `fork` startmethod. Or ditch pycharm and use `pdb`.

Comment: I read about this `set_start_method('fork')` but what would it effectivelly do? Isn't it the default option?

Comment: It is the default on UNIX-like systems like Linux and macOS. Ms-windows *must* use the `spawn` method because it lacks the `fork` system call. The `fork` system call creates an *identical copy* of a process. So both processes have the same code and data loaded into memory. *Only* the return value of `fork` differs in both processes so they know which one is the parent and which one the copy. It is incredibly convenient for `multiprocessing`, because the child *inherits* all the data in the parent process without effort.

Comment: I am on unix, how does specifiyng the start method help even when it is setting it to use the default method?

Comment: @GustavoMaia I suspect pycharm has something to do with it.